# CNN with a dynamic input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

**Hello everyone!**

Since I am trying to make a Fully Convolutional Neural Network which converts grayscale images to rgb images, I was wondering if I could train and test the model on different sized images (different pixels and ratio). Normally you would just downsample or upsample, what I do not want to do. I heared that it might be possible if I use a Fully Convolutional Neural Network, but I still have no clue what the code would look like. Could you help me out with some code?

**Why is this a problem?**

Like I said, the input image should not be downsampled, because I do not classify anything. I want to produce a new image with the same size as the input image. So there should not be any loss.

**Code for a fixed input shape:**

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
...
```

with images of the size 28*28px

**How I thought it might work:**

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(None, None, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
...
```

with images of different sizes

- image1 = 256*300
- image2 = 1024*800
- image3 = 500*400

[Here](https://blog.floydhub.com/colorizing-b-w-photos-with-neural-networks/) is an example of an autoencoder which converts grayscale images to rgb images, but this one has a fixed input shape.

[image]

*I am using TF 2.0 Alpha

Comment: Techniques to deal with different sizes: (1) Cropping / scaling and using multiple inputs for one prediction + combining results (2) FCN (3) Global Pooling. See [Analysis and Optimization of Convolutional Neural Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf) for details.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem? The approach you described above works; just make sure you don't have later any layers / steps where you need a fixed size. Usually when you want to actually classify stuff you have a fixed size. So if you don't have a very special loss function / target (e.g. later upsampling + same-shape target as the input as in the FCN paper), you combine FCN+Global pooling. Then you're happy.

Comment: I mean I have a specific loss function. I use a GAN

Comment: Cool :-) Can you try to make your code minimal and share the specific problem you're facing / the error message you get?

Comment: I actually didn't start to code the network cause I was struggling to find working code for this application. But I think your comment helps a lot, so thank you very much!

Comment: The bigger problem is that I can't find tensorflow code with undefined input shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, that a convolutional neural network does not care at all about the input shape. What it cares about, are kernel size, stride and padding. For example settingkernel size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1 does not change the tensors shape. When it comes to pooling, it must be assured, that padding = 1 is added, which is called **half/same padding** (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conv_arithmetic.html). Thus, it is possible to make a fully convolutional autoencoder which is able to process images of different sizes.